# youtube player api - playlist of video not created

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a youtube video player using the youtube player API as I need to be able to control the video using separate buttons.

I'm following this example for the moment, and trying to see if it works on my project: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2015/08/how-to-control-youtubes-video-player-with-javascript/

I literally just copied and pasted into my project and replaced the video ids, but with mine, the playlist is not generated and I don't really understand why.

this is my code:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('videoplaceholder', {
       videoId: '2CzXHiKIFps',
       playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            playlist: 'taJ60kskkns,FG0fTKAqZ5g'
        },
    });

    $('#play').on('click', function () {
        player.playVideo();
    });

    $('#pause').on('click', function () {
        player.pauseVideo();
    });

    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        player.nextVideo()
    });

    $('#prev').on('click', function () {
        player.previousVideo()
    });
}
```

in this pen you can see it in action:
http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/bpjyMK?editors=1010

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong, any help will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

If needed, this are the video IDs I need to use:

```
2CzXHiKIFps
Dqd0ZcwAg
Iv69Wd7f8-E
3ZPIi88jyHk
UMSAlyCtrSQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id `Dqd0ZcwAg` should be `r-Dqd0ZcwAg` (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-Dqd0ZcwAg)

This works:

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
   videoId: '2CzXHiKIFps',
    playerVars: {
        color: 'white',
        playlist: 'r-Dqd0ZcwAg,Iv69Wd7f8-E,3ZPIi88jyHk,UMSAlyCtrSQ'
    },
});
```